# Invariant subspaces and isotypic decomposition (reference request)

Tags: reference-request, rt.representation-theory

If $G$ is a (say) compact group and $V=\bigoplus_{i\in I}V_i$ the isotypic (a.k.a. primary) decomposition of a $G$-module, then

> any $G$-invariant subspace $W\subset V$ writes $W=\bigoplus_{i\in I}(W\cap V_i)$.

While this isn’t hard to prove (similar to Hoffman-Kunze 1971, [§7.5](//archive.org/details/LinearAlgebraHoffmanAndKunze/page/n270) for a single operator), it seems silly to redo it in a paper. Unfortunately, the only reference I’m familiar with omits the proof (Kirillov 1976, [§8.3](//books.google.com/books?id=11HxCAAAQBAJ&ots=CPps14aD40&pg=PA122&dq=%22Theorem+1%22)), and when using it (e.g. Lie groups [VIII.3.1](//books.google.com/books?id=oCO0xOzNLhAC&pg=PA86)) Bourbaki refers to such an abstrusely worded version (Algebra [VII.2.2](//books.google.com/books?id=GXT1CAAAQBAJ&ots=BSqgmQ9ECt&pg=PA253&dq=%22torsion+modules+over+a+principal+ideal+domain%22)) that unpacking it takes as much work as a direct proof.

**Q:** What is a good reference to quote for this? Bonus points if the case of non-algebraically closed fields is spelled out.

Comment: A better Bourbaki reference is Algèbre VIII, §4, Proposition 4 (unfortunately not yet translated, as far as I know). It works for semi-simple modules, no fields involved.

Comment: @abx Would you like to make your comment an answer? It is the one I wish I could accept, so far.

Comment: OK, done. $\qquad$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by the OP, I am turning my comment into an answer: a better Bourbaki reference is Algèbre VIII (new edition), §4, Proposition 4 d) (unfortunately not yet translated, as far as I know). It works for semi-simple modules over an arbitrary ring.

Comment: [Seems perfect](//books.google.com/books?id=9q8xDGbjHckC&ots=yru5D3W0BO&pg=PR6-IA52&dq=sous-module), thanks. The [earlier edition](//ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=20:4576) has it as VIII, §3, Proposition 9 b): “*Tout sous-module $\mathrm N$ de $\mathrm M$ est somme directe des $\mathrm N\cap\mathrm M_\lambda$*”.

Answer (score 1):

For compact groups you can quote [IV.2.7 in Naimark-Stern](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=793377). There the $T$-isotypical component is described as the image of an operator $E^T$.

For general semisimple categories it may be better to give a short modern proof. Define the center of the category. It is a product of division rings. Each simple object gives an idempotent in the center. This idempotent gives compatible idempotents in $Hom(V,V)$ and $Hom(W,W)$, which you can split off.

Comment: Thank you. Naimark and Stern’s long section 2.7 (pp. 199-205) has much useful material on the primary decomposition of a given $V$ (what they call $S$) and projectors onto a $V_i$ (what they call $\smash{E^T}$), but they don’t seem to state let alone prove results on restriction to arbitrary invariant $W\subset V$, do they?

Comment: They don't, you are right. They prove that $E^T$ is the projection $V\rightarrow V_{i}$, killing all other isotypical components. The operator does not depend on a representation. Since $V_i$ (or $W_i$) is the 1-eigenspace of $E^T$ on $V$ (or $W$), it is a basic Linear Algebra exercise to deduce the statement you need.